# Regex parsing in steps

Tags: python, regex, yield

Let's say I have the following string:

```
s = "once upon a time, there was once a person"
```

Without using `findall` to get all `once`s in the string:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\bonce\b', s)
['once', 'once']
```

Is there a way to use `search` incrementally, so it only returns the first occurrence and then increments the input string?

```
while (s):
    x = re.search(r'\bonce\b', s) # return 'once' and increment the string to s[4:]
    yield x
```

Comment: What do you mean by "increment" the string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- oh, it seems there is a builtin that I hadn't known before: `>>> for i in re.finditer(r'\bonce\b',s):
...     print i.group()`

Comment: Also, the `Match` object returned by `re.search` contains the position in the string that matched the regex so you can move forward in the string by slicing.

Comment: I was about to post an answer with `re.finditer`

Comment: @Barmar why not post an answer, I can accept that. Just show the options and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.finditer()`

```
for match in re.finditer(r'\bonce\b', s):
    yield match
```

Or you can just return the iterator rather than writing your own loop.

```
return re.finditer(r'\bonce\b', s)
```